# How can i extend the intellisense timeout in VSNET 2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2008, intellisense

Hope the subject line makes it clear. How can i extend the timeout for intellisense appearing in Visual Studio.

Most of the times, it so happens that i'm reading a description and the intellisense just fades out when i'm still not done.

Is there a place where i can tweak to extend the timeout explicitly.

Thanks and Cheers