# Visual Studio IntelliSense c# description timeout?

Tags: c#

Is there any way to change the timeout on the description of IntelliSense for Visual Studio 2012?  I often cannot read and comprehend the description before it times out.

Comment: afaik, there is no way to do it out of the box.. and there have been connect bugs reported as well. right from VS 2010... i don't think the issue was ever addressed. (or deemed important to be addressed) afaik.

Comment: there was a question like this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18269687/how-can-i-extend-the-intellisense-timeout-in-vsnet-2012, still not answered tho

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid that might be the case.  But the similar question was for VS 2010, and I was hoping something had been done about it.